# How to include a word in the command?

Tags: citing

I am using the cite command. I need the following output: [vgl. 1].

However, I don t know how to modify the cite command. Does someone know how I can do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are using `natbib` it works out of the box with `\cite[vgl.][]{...}`, but that's a big *if*. Please show us your bibliography setup.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `natbib` is loaded the `\cite` command is redefined to take two optional arguments. When only one is given, it is appended to the citation, as in normal LaTeX; when both are given, the first is prepended and the second appended.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{foo}, \cite[post]{foo}, \cite[pre][]{foo}, \cite[pre][post]{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo} Foo.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]